# React Native Firebase: How to retrive values (child) from one table to another copied table

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Db Structure]

As shown in Picture I have created a copy of tutor in which I am taking its refrence Id of child as "userId" and storing current userId in it, now on the basis of the userId from tutor table I want to fetch other record like username contactno etc from tutor to tutorCopy. Please help!
This is the code for coping the table and storing current user ID:

```
bookTutor = (item) => {
  var tab = firebase.database().ref().child("tutor/").child(item.userId).getKey();
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  firebase.database().ref('tutorCopy/' + tab).push({
    userId: user,
  }).then((data) => {
    //success callback

    console.log('data ', data)
    Toast.showWithGravity('Registered Successfully.', Toast.LONG, Toast.BOTTOM)

  }).catch((error) => {
    //error callback
    console.log('error ', error)
  });
}
```

Comment: have you written any code to try to do this?

Comment: No I actually don't know how to do it.

Comment: @imjared I have added the code which is coping table into tutorCopy